# Browser cannot load resource files

Tags: safari, webserver, firewall

We have a wildly 8.2 running on a virtualized ubuntu 14.04 behind a firewall (against DoS attacks,...) in a DMZ. (About 1200 - 3000 requests per hour.)
With Safari the download of some resource files often (about every 2nd time) fails (s. screenshot, all files are locally stored) while there is rarely a problem with other browsers (chrome, firefox)

1. Is there any plausible cause why there is a different behavior with Safari than with other browsers?
2. Has anybody ever had similar problems maybe regarding some firewall setting?
3. Is there any other hint where we could start looking for the cause of the problem? (Implementation, router, lack of resources...)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know, the question is a little unprecise, that's probably why it was voted down. But I'll post what the solution was anyway.

On the server side we ran a

```
tcpdump -i eth0 -n -A dst port 80 | grep 'specificUrlPath'
```

on some other (client) machine we issued a

```
 curl -X POST http://hostname/specificUrlPath
```

So we saw that the request did not always reach the server network interface and knew that there had to be a problem with the network in between.

The cause for the problem was, that NAT was switched on on the router for the server machine and the NAT implementation was obviously not able to manage as many connections. As soon as NAT was switched off everything worked as it should.
I am not sure, why requests of some browsers were more likely to be served than by others but I guess this is also due to the specific router software.